# Retrofit 2 best practice for android: asynchronous request or synchronous request in AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, retrofit

I am using the [Retrofit 2](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) library for an android REST client. Retrofit itself supports synchronous and asynchronous request (cf. [here](https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-synchronous-and-asynchronous-requests/)), the reason for the latter being not to block a thread and thus not to get interrupted by android.

In practice, is it better to use synchronous calls in a native `AsyncTask` or asynchronous calls directly from Retrofit?
If one is preferable over the other, what are the technical reasons?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One of the main reasons to use *any* of the popular REST clients (retrofit, volley, etc) is that they reduce the amount of details you have manage at the application layer.  One of those details is making sure your network requests happen off the main thread.  Why would one use an `AsyncTask` when a library they are already using for other features provides the same functionality with less ceremony?  The only reason I can think of is -- you don't think the library's threading is very good. That concern does not apply to retrofit 2, it uses `OkHttp` to dispatch async calls.  OkHttp has been around awhile and used extensively, it manages its own thread pool to execute async requests, and is solid.

So, the upside to using retrofit async is cleaner code, and no downside I know of vs `AsyncTask` with retrofit sync calls.  The only time I use the sync calls is when my code is already executing in a background thread for another reason. I never create a separate thread or asynctask just for the network call and use `enqueue` instead.